# When I add \raisebox in my third row all the other pictures go back to normal

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    ~                 & Horns rev 1 & Horns rev 2 & Anholt \\ \hline
    Antal møller      & 80   & 90 & 111    \\ \hline
    Effekt pr. mølle  & 2 MW   & 2.3 MW  & 3.6 MW \\ \hline
    Areal             & 20km$^2$ & 33km$^2$  & 88km$^2$      \\ \hline
    Samlede effekt    & 160MW  & 209MW & 400MW \\ \hline
    Effekt pr. areal  & 0.008 MW/m$^2$ & 0,0063 MW/m$^2$ & 0,0045 MW/m$^2$ \\ \hline
    Km kabel          & 55  & 72  & 185 \\ \hline
    kWh-pris          & 48 øre & 51.8 øre  & 105.1 øre\\ \hline
    Pris (mia. kr.)   & 2  & 3.5 & 9     \\ \hline
    Rotordiameter     & 80 meter & 93 meter  & 120 meter \\ \hline
    Formation & \raisebox{-3.5pt}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{frog.jpg}}
    & \raisebox{-3.5pt}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{frog.jpg}}  & \raisebox{-3.5pt}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{frog.jpg}}  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of a row is always determined by the highest/deepest elements. If all pictures are on the same level, there will be no extra space. Instead of raising the pictures, use the optional arguments of `\raisebox` to set the depth/height of at least one picture, using e.g.

```
\raisebox{0mm}[\dimexpr\height+1mm][1mm]{...}
```

This command will align the image at the bottom and add `1mm` of space at the top and at the bottom. The height of the image is measured automatically. To center the image vertically, you can use

```
\vcenterImage[... options like width and height of image ...]{... name of image ...}
```

where `\centerImage` is defined as

```
\newcommand\vcenterImage[2][]%
  {\raisebox
    {-\dimexpr0.5\height}%
    [\dimexpr0.5\height+1mm]%
    [\dimexpr0.5\height+1mm]%
    {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  }
```

(See below for examples of its usage.) In the sample code below, I propose some further improvements.

- Use rules sparingly, only when needed for orientation. This means: no vertical lines, and horizontal lines only every three text lines and for separating surrounding text from the table.
- Package `booktabs` provides better spacing of the table and nicer lines.
- Package `siunitx` provides better spacing of units. Most of its other features are not of immediate use here, but might be in the future.

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareSIUnit\ore{\text{øre}}
\newcommand\centerImage[2][]%
  {\raisebox
    {-\dimexpr0.5\height}%
    [\dimexpr0.5\height+1mm]%
    [\dimexpr0.5\height+1mm]%
    {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  }
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{llll}
  \toprule
                   &Horns rev 1       & Horns rev 2       &Anholt             \\
  \midrule
  Antal møller     &80                &90                 &111                \\
  Effekt pr.\ mølle&\SI{2.0}{MW}      &\SI{2.3}{MW}       &\SI{3.6}{MW}       \\
  Areal            &\SI{20}{km^2}     &\SI{33}{km^2}      &\SI{88}{km^2}      \\
  \midrule
  Samlede effekt   &\SI{160}{MW}      &\SI{209}{MW}       &\SI{400}{MW}       \\
  Effekt pr.\ areal&\SI{0.008}{MW/m^2}&\SI{0.0063}{MW/m^2}&\SI{0.0045}{MW/m^2}\\
  Km kabel         &55                &72                 &185                \\
  \midrule
  kWh-pris         &\SI{48.0}{\ore}   &\SI{51.8}{\ore}    &\SI{105.1}{\ore}   \\
  Pris (mia.\ kr.) &2.0               &3.5                &9.0                \\
  Rotordiameter    &\SI{80}{m}        &\SI{93}{m}         &\SI{120}{m}        \\
  \midrule
  Formation
    & \vcenterImage[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    & \vcenterImage[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    & \vcenterImage[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-a}                     \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use `\raisebox{0mm}[\dimexpr\height+2mm][2mm]{...}` so you don't have to hard-code the actual height. You can also suggest using `siunitx` for typesetting units.